# Software to make multiple transparent gifs

Tags: gif, transparency

Is there any software out there on the internet, preferably free, that can turn a large amount of images into transparent gifs (Assuming that all these files have the same background color that I want to set transparent)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [IrfanView.](http://www.irfanview.com/) Batch convert the file to .gif, and in the format options menu, check the 'Save Transparent GIF option'.